# Order By using Polish letters

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have problem with Order By. For example i have three words, in Polish: "Zzzz", "Żubr" and "Zajawka".

They should be sort like that:

```
Zajawka
Zzzz
Żubr
```

Cause Ż letter is after Z in polish alfabet. But it sorts to me:

```
Zajawka
Żubr
Zzzz
```

So it treats letter Ż like Z letter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the database wasn't created with a Polish collation. But you can always specify it when sorting:

```
SELECT   name
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY name COLLATE SQL_Polish_Cp1250_CS_AS_KI_WI
```

EDIT:
I misread the tags and assumed this was SQL Server. If you have a different RDBMS, please answer @RaphaëlAlthaus's question in the comments.

Comment: Im usin MysqL with Heidi SQL

Comment: The same syntax applies then, although MySQL does not seem to support a Polish collation. Take a look at [this list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html) - perhaps one of the Eastern European ones will apply, but I admit I have not checked this.

Comment: there's an `utf8_polish_ci` character set, but I found different answers on "does it sort polish characters" or not...

Answer (score 1):

you will have to re-sort after fetching records from database because it consider Ż as english character z.

you need to write custom re-sort method where you would just sort Ż after z.

or

You can fetch all records except Ż.

then in another query fetch all records of just Ż and append this list at the end of pre-fetched list.

Select all record which does not have Ż character in name
Select * from clients Where  client.name != *Ż* AND (my filter)

Select * from clients Where  client.name == *Ż* AND (my filter)

CodeBehind(c#):

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           List<Product> myList = new List<Product>();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            myList.Add(GetFromReader(dr));
        }

        if (dr.NextResult())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                myList.AddRange(GetFromReader(dr));
            }
        }
```