# Invalid sorting order in Eloquent while operating on post-wordpress database - polish letters

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, eloquent, collation

I have problem with proper ordering results in Eloquent.
We was forced to integrate Laravel with database that was created by Wordpress.
In our Laravel's API we'd like to order results that come from 'wp_post' table.

Everything works just fine exept we cannot properly sort results by 'post_title' field.
In polish language we have letter "Ż" which apparently is considered by MariaDB as normal "Z".

#### Example

```
$collection->orderBy('post_title', 'asc')
```

Will result with order:

> Zaa, Żbb, Zcc

While proper order is:

> Zaa, Zcc, Żbb

Our current table's charset is **utf8mb4** and collation is **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**

I've found similar issue here [Order By using Polish letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608651/order-by-using-polish-letters) and a couple of others in web, but I was unable to even change collation in database (for example to utf8mb4_polish_ci), because of SQL error:

> SQL Error [1067] [42000]: Invalid default value for 'post_date'
> Invalid default value for 'post_date'

The default value of 'post_date' (datetime) is '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

## UPDATE

Solved by simply changing

```
/** @var Builder $collection */
$collection->orderBy('post_title', 'asc')
```

to

```
/** @var Builder $collection */
$collection->orderByRaw('post_title COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci ASC')
```

Hope this will help someone

Comment: thank you ! i learnt something new :)